# In SCD Type2 how to find latest record

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, informatica

I have table i have run the job in scdtype 2 load the data below

---

```
no | name | loc |
-----------------
1  | abc  | hyd |
-----------------
2  | def  | bang |
-----------------
3  | ghi  | chennai |
```

---

then i have run the second run load the data given below

---

```
no | name | loc |
-----------------
1  | abc  | hyd |
-----------------
2  | def  | bang |
-----------------
3  | ghi  | chennai |
--------------------
1  | abc  |  bang |
```

---

here no dates,flags,and run ids
how to find second updated record in this situtation

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe you can. You should have dates and flags in your dimension (valid from date, valid to date, iscurrent flag would be a good start).

Comment: You definitively can't find *latest* record per primary key (`no`). What you *can do* ist to find all new records for  a given key (simple using `MINUS`). You'll get in troubles if there are more than one records for a given key to establish the sort order. So your interface is questionable.

Comment: You can't - due to the fact that this is not a proper SCD2 implementation. This needs to be redesigned.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll be able to distinguish between the updated record and the original record.

A Dimension table using Type 2 SCD requires additional columns that describes the period in which the record is valid (or current), exactly for this reason.

The solution is to ensure your dimension table has these columns (Typically ValidFrom and ValidTo dates or date/times, and sometimes an IsCurrent flag for good measure). Your ETL process would then populate these columns as part of making the Type 2 updates.